# Css files in Apache Tapestry 5.3.8 between projects

Tags: java, css, jetty, tapestry

I have an issue with Tapestry 5.3.8.

Let's assume we hae 3 projects: Gui, Main and Work. Gui project contains custom tapestry componenets. Main and Work are independent projects, both used Gui. I would like to have common css files for Main and Work in Gui.

Gui components are working and they are using Gui css. But is there any way that e.g. Main be using Gui css as well? E.g. I have a page in Main, on which I would like to use css from Gui.

"Context:" unfortunatley is not working... (asset not found)

Any hints would be welcome :)

Comment: If your gui project is included as dependency for main and work you can use all resources (assets and modules) that has gui project. You can import it via @Import(stylesheet="relative/path/to/css/asset.css")

Comment: Thanks for hint. But what do you mean by realtive? As a root I should state project name, like GUI/path/to/my/file.css? Or just /path/to/my/file/in/gui.css?

Comment: You can refer to http://tapestry.apache.org/assets.html. In short: this is path to asset relative to current class file. Also you can use absolute location in classpath  @Import(stylesheet="classpath:/com/gui/project/package/asset.css")

Comment: One more thing: where I should put my css files in gui? To some packege under "src/main/java" or in "src/main/webapp"

Comment: For tapestry prior to 5.4 to src/main/resources, for 5.4 and above into  META-INF/assets

Comment: There is also small hint: there is no possible to use "classpath" in tml pages. Only asset and context. But asset can be connected with ".." when you want to go "outside" current package - this was my solution.

Comment: xl0e - please write post, and I will mark it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **gui** project is included as dependency for **main** and **work** you can use all resources (assets and modules) that has **gui** project. You can import it via @Import(stylesheet="path/to/asset.css") placed to component or page class. Path can be either relative or absolute.

For tapestry prior to 5.4 to assets can be kept in src/main/resources, for 5.4 and above they should be in META-INF/assets